# Android: pass structuredName information to ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT does not work

Tags: android, android-intent

I tried to pass StructuredName information to ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT, it did not work. All other fields were fine.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
i.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)

ArrayList<ContentValues> data = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();



// add structured name, this does not work, the information do not show
// in the ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT activity

ContentValue row = new ContentValues();
row.put(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
row.put(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, "Test_family_name");
row.put(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, "Test_given_name");
data.add(row);`

// add other values...., all of them work

i.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA, data);
```

Comment: Not even with ACTION_INSERT too. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: No, I ended up giving up using ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT (or ACTION_INSERT).

Comment: Well I consider it for almost all items and used the extras for the name and address.

Comment: I posted a bug report for this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193804